# Get catalog details by magento api

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting all the catalog of magento by python but i want the specific info about the product but don't have any lead on that --

```
url='http://domain.com/api/xmlrpc/'
server_instance = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(url)
session = server_instance.login(API_USER, API_PASS)
inventory_list = 'catalog_product.list'
session, server_instance = getSession()
```

get session is a function for creating a session and server instance of this.

```
list = server_instance.call(session, inventory_list)
```

this returns me a list of a dictionary of all products having product id and SKU?
now how to get the info of that product?

Comment: have tried info method "catalog_product.info"?

Comment: AS @Abdul says, you can walk through the retrieved `list` and call the API for "catalog_product.info" providing the product ID you got from the list.

Comment: Abdul: Ty its working fine, a more doubt how to get the list of products that are assigned particular to a store, and the quantity of the products if that product is in enabled status ?  `product_stock.list ` getting the total quantity by this but not specific quantity of a store ...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sku and product_id ?

Try it!

```
for list in item:
    print "sku: " + item['sku'] + " && product_id: " + item['product_id']
```